# facebook tab fbml and dynamic content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

Per the new profile/fan page tab rule that eliminates the iFrame option, is there a way to dynamically generate content for a given tab? I've seen methods that wrap a canvas app (but requires a user to click to load content), but I want to show updated content thats managed on my servers. I thought you could also update the FBML using the Graph API, but haven't been able to find anything on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display static FBML on Application Tabs which is dynamically *generated*, you just can't auto-load anything that's dynamic on the client side (until the user clicks something)

You'll need to make sure you setup the application to be installable to pages as well.

Comment: I think the Application route is what's going to work. I don't want the app to be installed anywhere else, so I've made it only installable to pages and not users and not submitting it to the directory.

Comment: That's the pretty standard "pattern" for implementing what you're talking about.

Answer (score -2):

Go here for help on all things social media, especially FBML.

www.facebook.com/fanpagefactory

ask questions to the community or in the 24/7 live chat (you will get a timely response either way)

Enjoy.

Comment: If I had 125 points, I'd vote this down. Useless link points to crap.